# Действие после окончания отсчёта времени JS

Tags: javascript

Есть счётчик обратного отсчёта (до даты).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
timeend= new Date();
timeend= new Date(timeend.getYear()>1900?(timeend.getYear()+1):(timeend.getYear()+1901),0,1);
function time() {
    today = new Date();
    today = Math.floor((timeend-today)/1000);
    tsec=today%60; today=Math.floor(today/60); if(tsec<10)tsec='0'+tsec;
    tmin=today%60; today=Math.floor(today/60); if(tmin<10)tmin='0'+tmin;
    thour=today%24; today=Math.floor(today/24);
    timestr=today +" дней "+ thour+" часов "+tmin+" минут "+tsec+" секунд";
    document.getElementById('t').innerHTML=timestr;
    window.setTimeout("time()",1000);
}
</script>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы после окончания отсчёта (до нуля), скрипт перезагрузил страницу? Спасибо!

Comment: `location.href = "https://ваш.домен/роут";` или `location.reload()
`

Answer (score 0):

подсказываю:

```
//...
const isReload = (+timeend - +new Date()) < 0;
if (isReload) location.reload()
else window.setTimeout("time()",1000);
//...
```